# IE11 Saveas Frame Notification Bar children are unidentifiable using UIAutomation

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I am unable to automate IE11 save as functionality using UI automation as the Frame Notification Bar child elements are not identifiable via Inspect/UI spy or UI automation code. The same is working fine in other machines.

Edit:
Following are the screenshots of two different machine. at one machine the objects are getting identified and in another machine its not getting identified. 
I have tried to Reset also but nothing worked.
[In this system image objects are visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BsYF.png).
[in this system image objects are not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMZUN.png)

Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you mean, you are not able to see HTML elements using developer tools in IE 11 and because of that you are not able to use IE automation? If yes, I suggest you to reset your IE11 application and again try to check the elements using developer tools. If issue persists than try to share your webpage link. We will try to make a test with it. Let us know, If you see any warning or error message in your console.

Comment: Hi Deepak, Thanks for your reply. its not related to the developer toolbar. its related to the notication bar which appears when we try to download any file.

Comment: I have updated the screenshots of the issues in the question.

Comment: Can you please try to post your UI Automation code sample. We will try to make a test with your code to produce the issue on our side. It can help to narrow down the issue. Thanks for your understanding.